# How to rename files in subdirectories based on the name of the directory

Tags: bash, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to rename csv files in my subdirectory based on the name of the subdirectory while also adding _1.csv. For example: filename_1.csv, filename_2.csv for each file in a subdirectory.

I wrote a bash script but it doesn't give me the correct output.

```
#!/bin/bash
num=1
parent=/whois/v10_cctlds/full/
newfolder=/whois/csv7/
mkdir "$newfolder"
for folder in "$parent"/*; do
  if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
    foldername="${folder##*/}"
    for file in "$parent"/"$foldername"/*; do
      filename="${file##*/}"
      newfilename="$(foldername $num).csv"
      cp "$file" "$newfolder"/"$newfilename"
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: What does the input directory structure look like? What does the desired structure look like? What's the result you get?

Comment: `$(foldername $num)` looks fishy. This tries to run `foldername` as a command with argument `$num`.

Comment: You can save a couple of lines by using the pattern `"$parent"/*/` -- the trailing slash restricts the results to only directories.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, the input directory structure is a parent directory with lots of subdirectories. Most of the subdirectories only have one file inside but some up have to ten files inside. I want a new directory to be created called 'csv7' that contain all of the csvs files with the correct naming format. ex: newfilename_1.csv. If I take the '$num' part out of line 10 I get a bunch of files without the _1.csv part.

Comment: @brandon, do you have a script or exported function named `foldername` that takes "1" as a parameter? I think you want `newfilename="${filename}_$num.csv"`

Comment: I also don't see you incrementing `$num`

Comment: I did add an counter by saying num=+1 but that still doesn't fix the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
parent=/whois/v10_cctlds/full/
newfolder=/whois/csv7/

for i in `ls $parent`
do
        let num=1
        for a in `ls $parent/$i`
                do mv $parent/$i/$a $newfolder"$i"_$num.csv
                num=`expr "$num" + 1`
                done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately when I run bash script it tells me that the file that the script is trying to create is the same as the file that already exists.

Comment: There are several issues with this code. Paste it into https://www.shellcheck.net for details.

Comment: hi Brandon, just changed. try with this now

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want this, which incorporates my comments.

```
#!/bin/bash
parent=/whois/v10_cctlds/full/
newfolder=/whois/csv7/
mkdir -p "$newfolder"

for folder in "$parent"/*/; do
    num=0
    foldername=$(basename "$folder")
    for file in "$folder"/*; do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
            cp -v "$file" "$newfolder/${foldername}_$((++num)).csv"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: This is close but it doesn't incorporate the name of the subdirectory into the file name.

Comment: Where in your question can we see that requirement?

Comment: Hi Glen, I apologize I was not very clear. Let's say I have a subdirectory called 123, I want the file in the subdirectory to be called 123_1.csv

Comment: Looks better now?